# How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have below similar report in Jaspersoft iReport Designer, but not able to figure out how to sum all values present in vertical column "Doctor Payment" to get a total of "1601"? Length of this columns is variable (i.e. no of rows vary according to size of database & its update frequency ).

Is there any variable like `$V{COLUMN_COUNT}` (actually gives no of rows, here 5),
which gives sum of all values in a column? If no, how to do **sum**?

```
Doctor ID   Doctor Payment
 A1             123
 B1             223
 C2             234
 D3             678
 D1             343
Total          1601
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It is quite easy to solve your task. You should create and use a new variable for summing values of the **"Doctor Payment"** column.

In your case the variable can be declared like this:

```xml
<variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{payment}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

- the *Calculation type* is **Sum**;
- the *Reset type* is **Report**;
- the *Variable expression* is **$F{payment}**, where **$F{payment}** is the name of a field contains sum (*Doctor Payment*).

The working example.

*CSV datasource:*

```
doctor_id,payment
A1,123
B1,223
C2,234
D3,678
D1,343
```

*The template:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="doctor_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="payment" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{payment}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Doctor ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Doctor Payment]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{doctor_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{payment}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

*The result will be:*

[image: Generated report via iReport's preview]

---

You can find a lot of info in the [*JasperReports Ultimate Guide*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf).

Comment: I got some logic,but where to put new variable,i am putting at starting,i.e. after many </field name> declared,but give error that variable not found:"total"

Comment: @SagarNikam Did you try my sample?

Comment: yes,sir with your sample it works,but i switch to real time data,working with mysql query,it gives error "variable not found",i declare variable after </queryString> over,sould i send complete file

Comment: @SagarNikam It should be a new question

Comment: That is not correct as you bind on field not table column

Comment: Hi @AlexK can the above example take a bean as a datasource as it is not a table?

Comment: @L-Samuels Yes, it can be a bean datasoure

Comment: @AlexK if the column was instead

<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subBean}.getPayment()]]></textFieldExpression>

Then how will i sum the total?

Comment: @L-Samuels It will be something like this: `<field name="payment" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$F{subBean}.getPayment()]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
...
<variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{payment}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
...
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[payment]]></textFieldExpression>
...
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[total]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: I ve been trying that but i cant get past the JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : $F{subBean}.getPayment()

....By the way is this right?  <subDataset name="dataset1">
  <field name="subBean" class="com.blahblah.SubBean">
   <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
  </field>
 </subDataset>

Comment: @L-Samuels It is better to post the question :)

Answer (score 26):

iReports Custom Fields for columns 
(sum, average, etc)

1. Right-Click on Variables and click Create Variable
2. Click on the new variable

   a.   Notice the properties on the right
3. Rename the variable accordingly
4. Change the Value Class Name to the correct Data Type

   a. You can search by clicking the 3 dots
5. Select the correct type of calculation
6. Change the Expression

   a.    Click the little icon

   b.    Select the column you are looking to do the calculation for

   c.    Click finish
7. Set Initial Value Expression to 0
8. Set the increment type to none
9. Leave Incrementer Factory Class Name blank
10. Set the Reset Type (usually report)
11. Drag a new Text Field to stage (Usually in Last Page Footer, or Column Footer)
12. Double Click the new Text Field
13. Clear the expression “Text Field”
14. Select the new variable
15. Click finish
16. Put the new text in a desirable position 