# Is there way to generate table with subtotal in Jasper Report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is there way to generate table with subtotal in Jasper Report?

I already get some [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer) for subtotal using `querystring`. I want to use `subDataset` and `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`. How can I do in template for subtotal?

template

```
<subDataset name="dataSource">
    <field name="product" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="qty" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.Date"/>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="TableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
....
<jr:table ...>
    <datasetRun subDataset="dataSource">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{TableDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
    ......  
</jr:table>
```

program

```
list.add(new Product("AAA", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("AAA", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("AAA", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("BBB", 200, date));
list.add(new Product("BBB", 150, date));
list.add(new Product("BBB", 100, date));
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
```

Expected output

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
|Product |    Date   |  Qty  |
+--------+-----------+-------+
|AAA     | 08-08-210 | 100   |
|        | 08-09-210 | 100   |
|        | 08-10-210 | 100   |
+--------+-----------+-------|
|           SubTotal | 300   |
+--------+-----+-------------+
|BBB     | 08-08-210 | 200   |
|        | 08-09-210 | 150   |
|        | 08-10-210 | 100   |
+--------+-----------+-------|
|           SubTotal | 450   |
+--------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: What about using groupings?

Comment: yes, This is what I want. I only get reference with `querystring`. I would like to use `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`.

Comment: Are you using iReport? If so, try create a group by product or description.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, I use it. It cannot create because of these field is inside of `subDataset'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple to calculate it out of the report and place in the DataSource

```
list.add(new Product("AAA", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("AAA", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("AAA", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("TOTAL:", 300, date)); //total AAA
list.add(new Product("BBB", 200, date));
list.add(new Product("BBB", 150, date));
list.add(new Product("BBB", 100, date));
list.add(new Product("TOTAL:", 450, date)); //total BBB
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
```

UPDATE: You can calculate the same on DB level

```
select 0 as ord, * from t
union all
select 1 as ord, 'Total' as product, sum(Qty) as Qty, null as date from t group by
order by ord, product
```

Comment: I just show as example, How about this list from db?

Comment: Plz, check my update post, Report template have to autocratically column span for name and Date...

Answer (score 0):

You can use report grouping. Here's what you should be doing.

- Take a sub report move your data there.
- Take a group which changes on product name i.e. `AAA` in sub report.
- Take a variable that resets on group change and that calculates the sum `Qty`.

For more reference on report groups visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_groups.htm) link.

**EDIT :**

Alternatively you can use report scriplets to accomplish it. Visit [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_scriptlets.htm) for more on report scriplets.

I suggest you use `report scriplets` this would save you from creating sub reports and report froups.

Comment: thank you. please check my post, I already get it. Which is used `queryString`, `field` tag is outside. If so, `group` can bind it. My `field` is inside of `subDataset` tag. It cannot be done. Have you try with `subDataset`? Not `queryString`