# How can I show sum of columns in column header?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to design a Jasper report in iReport 5 tool with the following constraints:

1. I need to show the sum of each column in the header like in the image
2. I need to show the columns vertical like in the image

Desired output

[image: expected output]

Is it possible to design report like this?

Comment: Voting to re-open, the answer can be contained in a couple of lines (hence not to broad), furthermore it is a duplication target for other similar questions

Answer (score 3):

Using the normal `detail` band and `columnHeader` band  this is achieved by creating a variable with `calculationType="sum"` on the field you like to sum

See:
[How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer)

Then display the variable using a `textField` in the `columnHeader` band, setting `evaluationTime="Report"` so that variable is calculated before displaying it.

To rotate a `textElement` vertical use the `rotation` attribute (`rotation="Left"`)

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ReportTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="43c90ca5-f3c3-4dda-8423-9ff1442f90e3">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from mytable]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="descr" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="sumValue" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="70">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="50" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="dfe13f55-12a6-4c33-b5ba-00dd61f37c96"/>
                <box leftPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["TOTALE"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="###0.00;-###0.00">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="50" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="ed251db0-474e-4e20-8788-3c2f08bfd1e7"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="50" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="62b62711-8cfb-4df2-8f9e-4a34249dcc66"/>
                <box leftPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Left">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SESSIONS]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="6a009a8c-16de-451c-a0f1-516a48f793d0"/>
                <box leftPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="###0.00;-###0.00">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="1fccff95-408c-4364-b003-c691fefdde62"/>
                <box rightPadding="2">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result** (with some arbitrary data)

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

if you're not familiar with crosstab, as previously suggested, you could create a subreport just to show the column totals and put it "before" the detail band (for example in the page header band).

obviously, following this way, you will access the datasource twice, and this could could be something you want to avoid, especially if time matters.

basically, a crosstab is the better solution overall, but if you need something simpler (maybe you're not familiar with iReport) or one-shot-like you could think about a subreport

Answer (score 0):

in this type of reports, you can use a crosstab, you put a field than name it monthly. Use in the columns and a field name it month in rows, and use the sum function in cells

```xml
<crosstab>
    <rowGroup name="month" width="128" totalPosition="End">
        ...
    </rowGroup>
    <columnGroup name="monthlyUse" height="66">
            ...
    </columnGroup>
    <measure name="nameMeasure" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></measureExpression>
    </measure>              
    ....                
</crosstab>
```

the crosstab will generate a table shwoing the monthly usage with a total row

Comment: You can use crosstab, but actually there is no need. It can also be done on normal report with columnHeader and detail band

Comment: in my sql query dataset i have two columns 1.Month name 2.total item in that month....for example first row is April with 24 items and May with 24 items then with crosstab i want to show sum of item columns .... but i am not able to do that...

Comment: mithlesh singh specify whats exactly the problem? you have two fields (month name and total item) when creating the crosstab you select month name in Row Group then total item in Column Group, then you have to use another field you name it number for example, it should be an Integer or Double, you select number in the Data and select function Sum