# Displaying sum of a column in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm looking at displaying the sum of a column in iReport. I'm using netbeans, java and sqlite as database. Basically, I want to group the report by department and show each department's total overtime listing each staff's overtime in 1 line too.

E.g. from database:

Name             Date      Department  Overtime Hours

Employee1       09/22     Management      3.0

Employee1       09/23     Management      2.0

Employee2       09/22     Management      1.0

Employee3       09/23        HR           2.0

Employee3       09/23        HR           2.5

What I want to display in the report is like this:

Department: Management

Name                   Total Overtime

Employee1               5.0

Employee2               1.0

Total Overtime : 6.0

Department: HR

Employee3               4.5

Total Overtime: 4.5

I've checked the link below and it helped a bit but I couldn't do it in a way as I described above. If anyone can help pointing me to a direction how this can be done, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

[How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer)