# Ireports - sum null values and values

Tags: jasper-reports

I was wondering how I can sum values in Ireports 
For example I have some "null" and some values (5,10,200..etc) 
I want to sum them in a third column .

I have $F(field1) - 5 
$F(field2) - Null 
$(field3) - Null 
So in total , no matter that I have '5' as result from 'Field1' - I always get "Null"  (After running the jasper ) [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ywR3.png)
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgxmZ.png)

Please check screenshots

Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum all values in a column in Jaspersoft iReport Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550514/how-to-sum-all-values-in-a-column-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer)

Comment: `<variable name="sumOfField1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum"><variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1} != null ? $F{field1} : 0]]></variableExpression>` - for int type

Answer (score 2):

To calculate sum for Total column use following expression:

```
($F{field1} == null ?  0:$F{field1}) + ($F{field2} == null ?  0:$F{field2}) +($F{field3} == null ?  0:$F{field3})
```

You may need to convert this variables into the respective datatypes. (Integer or Double)

Comment: Thank you so much!! Solved!